# Is COM+ still recommended?

Tags: .net, asp.net, com+

I used to write ASP.Net apps deploying business dataaccess layers in COM+ components several years ago. This was the standard in several corporate infrastructure here in my country. Is this still recommended? What is the alternative?

Answer (score 5):

COM+ is really just MTS ([Microsoft Transaction Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Transaction_Server)) rebadged and bundled with Windows 2000 and later versions (it was an optional extra on NT4).  If you're using non-managed code, COM+ is still the preferred option for a transactional middle-tier.  In fact, it's usually used as the TP monitor in [TPC-C](http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/results/tpcc_perf_results.asp) benchmark systems because it's more efficient than .Net or Java and much cheaper than Tuxedo or Encina (which reduces the $/TPM).

WCF ([Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)) has its own transaction monitor, which is reasonable as the architecture of COM+ is tightly coupled to COM and would be difficult to retrofit a .Net runtime to.  If you're writing a transactional application in .Net, WCF provides this facility although the [System.Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254973.aspx) library also provides distributed transaction support for ADO.Net clients.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of talk about WCF here, but I honestly don't think that's what you're looking for.

In the early days of ASP, people quickly learned that placing all of the code in the markup pages was difficult to maintain.  As a result, some people started implementing N-Tier designs using COM components.  If your intentions are to simply build a DAL in a typical N-Tier fashion, there is no reason that a simple class library wouldn't suffice.

Look into building a class library, adding it as a reference to your web project and, of course, [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

WCF is the new recommended mechanism for interobject communication

Comment: COM+ is a transaction monitor, not just an IPC mechanism.

Comment: What did you do?  Read COM+ and make the jump to the closest replacement for the technology?  I'm shocked that this is the highest ranked answer when it's most likely not even necessary to use WCF.  The architecture of the original project is likely wrong.  Read what he's trying to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

I have just spent the past two days trying to make two of my old COM+ business objects work on a new Windows 2003 Server and I am certain I never want to work with COM+ ever again.

Comment: I've also encountered issues with COM+ migration to win2k3. 
In my case, I had to change the security settings for my COM+ app. 
In the 'Identity' tab, I changed the account from the 'Interactive User' to a new local machine account.

Answer (score -3):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686988(VS.85).aspx:

> "COM+ is the next step in the evolution of the Microsoft® Component
>   Object Model and Microsoft Transaction Server (MTS). COM+ handles many
>   of the resource management tasks you previously had to program
>   yourself, such as **thread allocation** and **security**. It
>   **automatically** makes your applications **more scalable** by providing **thread pooling**, **object pooling**, and **just-in-time
>   object activation**. COM+ also helps protect the integrity of your
>   data by providing transaction support, even if a transaction spans
>   multiple databases over a network."

Although looks like a kind of legacy stuff, I dont' think any single fashion technology provided by Microsoft at this time can replace COM+.